# Apply function to elements of dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have the following dataframe `df`

```
              1      3
Scenario1  0.001   0.05
Scenario2  0.003   0.01
Scenario3  0.001   0.042
Scenario4  0.09    0.006
Scenario5  0.02    0.04
```

Suppose these are interest rates and periods and I want to compute the annuity.

If you are not familiar with it think I just want to apply this formula:

```
    def computeAnnuity(r,n):
        return (1-(1+r)**-n)/r
```

How can I get a dataframe where for each element I have computed the value of the function before?

I would like to do something like

```
df.applymap(computeAnnuity)
```

giving as `r` the return (each element in the df) and as `n` the columns' name of the dataframe (that are 1 and 3). But I do not know how to do it in an efficient way without looping or doing for cycles.

In other words to give you a practical example for Scenario1 period 1 where there is 0.001 I want `(1-(1+0.001)**-1)/0.001` or, for instance, for Scenario4 period 3 where I have 0.006 I want `(1-(1+0.006)**-3)/0.006`. I would like to do it for every element in the dataframe (in an efficient and automatic way: using the function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need `apply`:

```
def computeAnnuity(r,n):
    return (1-(1+r)**-n)/r

df1 = df.apply(lambda x: computeAnnuity(x, x.name))
print (df1)
                  1         3
Scenario1  0.999001  2.723248
Scenario2  0.997009  2.940985
Scenario3  0.999001  2.764591
Scenario4  0.917431  2.964357
Scenario5  0.980392  2.775091

print ((1-(1+0.001)**-1)/0.001)
0.9990009990008542
```

Answer (score 2):

For performance (since we are looking for efficiency here), I would suggest a `NumPy` based approach that uses [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
a = df.values
N = df.columns.values.astype(int)
df_out = pd.DataFrame((1-(1+a)**-N)/a, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]: 
               1      3
Scenario1  0.001  0.050
Scenario2  0.003  0.010
Scenario3  0.001  0.042
Scenario4  0.090  0.006
Scenario5  0.020  0.040

In [42]: df_out
Out[42]: 
                  1         3
Scenario1  0.999001  2.723248
Scenario2  0.997009  2.940985
Scenario3  0.999001  2.764591
Scenario4  0.917431  2.964357
Scenario5  0.980392  2.775091
```

**Further boost with `numexpr` module**

Looking at the computations involved, it seems we are dealing with `power` and `division` based operations. These could be leveraged with [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide) module for further boost in performance.

Thus, we would have two approaches, like so -

```
import numexpr as ne

def numpy_app(df):
    a = df.values
    N = df.columns.values.astype(int)
    return pd.DataFrame((1-(1+a)**-N)/a, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)

def numpy_numexpr_app(df):
    a = df.values
    N = df.columns.values.astype(int)
    return pd.DataFrame(ne.evaluate('(1-(1+a)**-N)/a'), \
                            columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

Runtime test on bigger dataset -

```
In [75]: names = np.random.choice(10000,5000, replace=0)

In [76]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5000,5000), columns=list(names))

# @jezrael's solution using df.apply
In [77]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: computeAnnuity(x, int(x.name)))
1 loops, best of 3: 3.54 s per loop

In [78]: %timeit numpy_app(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.99 s per loop

In [79]: %timeit numpy_numexpr_app(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 393 ms per loop
```